# Error with reading data from SQLite database Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to read data from my SQLite Database I created in android studio. I keep receiving the error "Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0". I assume it has to do with my ReadData Function but I'm not sure what needs to be fixed. I'm trying to read data fro a specific row of a specific column to a variable in another activity. The database is connected but the data I'm trying to pass through to the other activity is giving me an error. If more explanation is needed please let me know.

---------THIS IS THE LINE IN MY ACTIVITY THAT GIVING ME THE ERROR IN LINE 980 OF BallProcessDataActivity

```
distance = databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"distance").getFloat(i);
```

--------------IN MY DATABASE HELPER JAVA CLASS---------------------

```
public Cursor ReadData(int rowNum, String columnName){
        String query = "SELECT '" + columnName + "'"+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = '" + rowNum + "';";

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor res = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

        res.close();
        return res;


    }
```

----------------------HERE IS THE ERROR I RECEIVE-----------------

```
2020-07-30 12:51:27.238 17801-17801/wtzn.wtbtble901 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: wtzn.wtbtble901, PID: 17801
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{wtzn.wtbtble901/wtzn.wtbtble901.BallProcessDataActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:515)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:76)
        at wtzn.wtbtble901.BallProcessDataActivity.ShotAnalyze(BallProcessDataActivity.java:980)
        at wtzn.wtbtble901.BallProcessDataActivity.onCreate(BallProcessDataActivity.java:969)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: So do not ask to read a long for the first element (with i==0) from an empty collection (size==0). Check for non empty before use.

Comment: I know the database isnt empty though. I can open the database in an sqlite viewer and it shows that there is in fact data in it. about 400 entries

Comment: Your database may have a lot of data. But that is not the point. You made a selection and the selection was empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number or rows in the result set

```
Cursor res = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
if (res.getCount() > 0) {
   res.moveToPosition(rowNum);
} else {
   // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `ID` is the primary key of your table, your query (if it was syntactically correct) would return only 1 row with only 1 column.
So you shouldn't be using `i` as a parameter to `getFloat(i)` unless `i` is `0`, because the only column's index is `0`.
Also you should not close the `Cursor` that your method returns.
You can close it after you call the method and use it, when it is no longer needed.
In your query you must not concatenate single quotes around the column's name and use a `?` placeholder for the parameter `rowNum`:

```
public Cursor ReadData(int rowNum, String columnName){
    String query = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = ?";
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {String.valueOf(rowNum)});
    return res;
}
```

Now call the method `ReadData()` like this:

```
Cursor c = databaseHelper.ReadData(i, "distance");
if (c.moveToFirst()) distance = c.getFloat(0);
c.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! So if i had a function like this would i need multiple cursors?:                 accLinear = AccLinear(databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"aX").getFloat(i), databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"aY").getFloat(i), databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"aZ").getFloat(i), databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"q0").getFloat(i), databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"q1").getFloat(i), databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"q2").getFloat(i), databaseHelper.ReadData(i,"q3").getFloat(i));

Comment: This would be totally inefficient. If you want more than 1 columns of the same row, make a Cursor that returns all the columns of the row and don't use 1 Cursor for each column.